# How do I add an attribute name to an array?

Tags: python, numpy, pymc

I was wondering how to add an attribute to an array.

When I do

```
errors1 = pm.Uniform('errors', 0, 100, size = 7)
```

the name 'errors' is added.

but then when I do

```
 errors2 = [errors1[1], errors1[3], errors1[6]]
```

I have no idea how to add that name, and because I didn't add it, when I try to create a model with errors2, I get an error, saying that it doesn't have an attribute name.

Here's my full code:

```
import pymc as pm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pymc.Matplot import plot as mcplot
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc

first_res = [-27.020,3.570,8.191,9.898,9.603,9.945,10.056]
second_res = [18.752, 12.450, 11.832]

v1 = pm.Uniform('v1', -30, 15)
v2 = pm.Uniform('v2', 0, 20)

errors1 = pm.Uniform('errors', 0, 100, size = 7)
errors2 = [errors1[1], errors1[3], errors1[6]] # doesn't have an attribute name

taus1 = 1/(errors1 ** 2)
taus2 = [taus1[1], taus1[3], taus1[6]]

first_dist = pm.Normal('first_dist', mu = v1, tau = taus1, value = first_res, observed = True)
second_dist= pm.Normal('second_dist', mu = v2, tau = taus2, value = second_res, observed = True)

model=pm.Model([first_dist, second_dist, errors1, taus1, v1, v2])
mcmc=pm.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(20000,10000)

mcplot(mcmc.trace("errors"))

plt.figure() 

model2=pm.Model([second_dist, errors2, taus2, v2]) # since errors2 doesn't have an attribute name, I get an error
mcmc2=pm.MCMC(model2)
mcmc2.sample(20000,10000)

mcplot(mcmc2.trace('second_dist'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyMC2` has some magic that lets us operate on nodes like `errors1` as if they are numpy arrays, but it doesn't always work as you might expect.  In cases like this, you can define a deterministic node explicitly with the `pm.Lambda`, e.g.

```
errors2 = pm.Lambda('errors2', lambda errors1=errors1: [errors1[1],
                                                        errors1[3], 
                                                        errors1[6]])
```

Comment: thanks, but I still get an error saying "TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string", maybe errors2, is not the problem..

Comment: Here is a notebook which runs for me (modulo convergence issues): http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/452b9d8993c235743e73 

Does this work for you?

Comment: Actually, never mind, I just wrote two separate programs. But your answer answers everything, so I will upvote and accept.

Comment: do you know how to output first_dist and second_dist from my code?

Comment: Since `first_dist` is observed, it does not have a trace.  You can access `first_dist.value` and `first_dist.logp`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify on some python concepts, the way you define `errors2`, it is a python list. lists do not have any name attribute. The attributes that have the elements of a list are not the same attributes of the list as a whole (as an object).
In fact, arrays do not have any name attribute either, and if `errors1` does have a name attribute it is because it is pymc object, a distribution.

I think you have to define `errors2` in more detail. Is it a uniform distribution? What is its relation to errors1, not in python, but statistically?